# Why is the_post_thumbnail always getting called?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I'm developing a wordpress theme, and in my header.php I believe I have valid code, but for some reason, the thumbnail image is always shown in the code below.

The logic I'm trying to achieve is:

```
if this is the homepage, and the s3slider plugin has been installed
   show the slider
else if this page has a featured image (the_post_thumbnail)
   show the thumbnail
else
   show a default image
```

My code block is:

```
if (is_front_page() && function_exists(s3slider_show()) ) {
//we're on the homepage, and s3Slider exists
    s3slider_show();
} elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
//there is a featured image / thumbnail
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    // the current post lacks a thumbnail
    ?><img alt="alt text" src="image.jpg" />
    <?php
}
```

I can't for the life of me work it out, even though on the homepage the slider is shown, so is the_post_thumbnail() output.

Is it too late, and I've forgotten something fundamental?

I don't see why the_post_thumbnail will even be executed on the homepage if I've already entered the first if for the home / s3Slider combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`function_exists()`](http://www.php.net/function-exists) expects a string:

```
function_exists( 's3slider_show' )
```

Since your function `s3slider_show` doesn't return a string the first condition evaluates always to `false`.

Comment: Ahhh... silly me. And of course the slider was being shown because I was calling the function in the function_exists(). Thanks!